# retrieving current user to show in personal profile

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

hi im trying to retrive current user info from firebase but its showing me errors this error

[image]

this is my code

```
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: db
                  .collection("Users")
                  .doc("list_students")
                  .collection("Students")
                  .doc(user!.uid)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center();
                }
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Stack;
```

this is a screenshots of my firebase
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to print 'snapshot' and 'snapshot.data' for you've got proper data from firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `snapshot.data` as a `List` type before you can call the `length` method on `snapshot.data`. I cannot tell from your included code what is the underlying type for `snapshot.data`.

Another way is to specify `AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot` in the `builder` header, assuming the underlying data type is a `List<String>`.